# ROM Soong error: unrecognized module type

Tags: android, linux, clang, prebuild, lineageos

I'm tried to build RR Pie for Z00ED and on the first ten seconds I get the following output ([full output](https://pastebin.com/45957bwe)). I'm tried to use device repos from [here](https://github.com/Asus-MSM8916):

Thanks for all the help!

```
[1/1] /home/user/android/rr/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build /home/user/android/rr/out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: /home/user/android/rr/out/soong/build.ninja 
/home/user/android/rr/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l /home/user/android/rr/out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b /home/user/android/rr/out/soong -n /home/user/android/rr/out -d /home/user/android/rr/out/soong/build.ninja.d -o /home/user/android/rr/out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:17:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:24:1: unrecognized module type "llvm_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:32:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:42:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:52:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:62:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:72:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:82:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:92:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_llndk_library"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:102:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_llndk_library"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:112:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_llndk_library"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:122:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_llndk_library"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:132:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_llndk_library"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:142:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_llndk_library"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:152:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:166:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:180:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:194:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:208:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:222:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_shared"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:236:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:250:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:264:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:278:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:292:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:306:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:320:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:331:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:342:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:353:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:364:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
error: prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/Android.bp:375:1: unrecognized module type "libclang_rt_prebuilt_library_static"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:35:43 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

You can see the other thread [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/rom-soong-error-unrecognized-module-type-t4132971) where I solved my problem.

The solution is to re-init the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your repo init & sync had problems. Re-init the repo.